# Getting garbage data while tring to read a file

Tags: java, html, file, jsp, filereader

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8082/newsletter/comments/"+rs.getString("articlename"));
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String buf=" ";
while((buf = in.readLine())!= null){
  out.write(buf);
  out.flush();
}
in.close();
```

So this is the code I am working on. The file that is being read is displaying junk values on the page. The content displayed is huge whereas the file consists of only one line. Please help.

Here is the example of junk that is being displayed:

```
PK!Ýü?7f [Content_Types].xml ¢( ´TËnÂ0¼Wê?D¾V?¡?ªªú8¶H¥`ìXõKöòúûnDUA*å)YïÌììÄ?ÑÚ?l  1iïJÖ/z,'½ÒnV²?ÉK~Ï²?Â)a¼??m ±Ñðúj0ÙHu»T²9bxà<É9X?ÀQ¥òÑ¤×8ãAÈO1~ÛëÝqé?Ãk6$N{9?êÍ+P9Y ¢?vuÇGD²ìÃï?»ÆoR??wàÍ³¶ÌIÊ?~???8?ïWòZè?"V0}¿?ûßÀ»?´ù?>þÁ?ýuQwHoî·áÿÿPK!?·óN_rels/.rels ¢( ??ÛJA?ïßaÈ}7Û"ÒÙÞH¡w"ë??ìwÌ¤Ú¾½£ ºPÛ^æôçËOÖ???Ô;§<¯aYÕ Ø?`Gßkxm·?PYÈ[??gGÎ°inoÖ/"f3°£\?È¾Tº?I    S??Ìõ?«º¾ÇôW??¦ÚYigï@µÇX6_Ö]7~fïØË?ÈaoÙ.b*lIÆr?j)õ,l0Ï%??b¬6ài¢ÕõDÿ_???,    ¡   ?Ïó|u?Z^tÙ¢yÇ¯;!Y,}{ûC?³/h>ÿÿPK!Öd³Qú1word/_rels/document.xml.rels ¢( ¬?ÍjÃ0?ï?¾?Ø{-;ý¡?È¹?@®­û?½þ¡²$´?¶~ûCR?÷â?`Fhæ?´?íwoÄ'ê?U?%)´¥«:Û(x/vwÏ ?µ­´qH°Íoo6¯h4ÇCÔv?DL±¤ eök)©l±×?8?6îÔ.ô?£?ôºüÐÊU?>É0Í?ü"Sì+a_Ý?(?ÿÏvuÝ?øâÊc??¯TÈ/<¼!s¼ÅXd3?
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the "junk values"?

Comment: is the file in question an xml file?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow nope a docx file :/

Comment: iirc, docx files actually are xml files.

Comment: I'm quite new to this concept. What can be done to get what is actually stored in the file? @WoodrowBarlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read a word document (docx), you need to use the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) framework. You will specifically want to use the `XWPF` and `HWPF` portion, the documentation can be found [here.](https://poi.apache.org/document/index.html)

Comment: It gives the same output :/

Comment: So even if I add the jar file specified in the read, the content displayed is garbage.
The jar file I included is poi-ooxml-3.7.jar

Comment: It's not about just adding the .jar file. You need to use it. There are examples of how to use the framework in the links provided.